# Error in pandas scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to visualize the [Galton Height Data](http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Galton.html).  I've copied and pasted the data into a txt file, and converted it to an `.xlsx` file using the following code:

```
with open('Galton_height_Data.txt','r') as f:

data = []

for i in f:
    z = i.strip('\n')
    z = z.split('\t')
    data.append(z)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( data[1:], columns = data[0] )

df.to_excel('Galton_Height.xlsx')
```

Now,  I would like to visualize the data using a scatter plot.  I am trying to visualize the Mother's height vs the Child's height in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn


df = pd.read_excel("Galton_Height.xlsx")

ax = df.plot( kind = 'scatter' , x = df['Mother'], y = df['Height'])
```

The following error is returned:

```
`KeyError: '[ 67.   67.   67.   67.   66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  64.   64.   64.   64.\n  64.   64.   64.   58.5  58.5  58.5  58.5  58.5  58.5  68.   68.   68.\n  68.   68.   68.   68.   66.5  66.5  66.5  66.   65.5  62.   62.   62.\n  62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   61.   67.   67.   66.5  66.5  66.5  65.\n  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   64.5  64.5  64.5  64.5\n  64.5  64.5  64.   64.   64.   63.   69.   69.   69.   69.   69.   69.\n  69.   69.   68.   68.   68.   67.   67.   67.   65.   65.   65.   65.\n  65.   65.   65.   65.5  64.   64.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.\n  63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.5  63.5  63.5  62.\n  62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.\n  62.   62.   62.   62.   61.   69.   69.   69.   69.   69.   67.   67.\n  67.   67.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.\n  66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5\n  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   64.   64.   64.\n  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.5  64.5  64.5  64.5  64.   64.   64.\n  64.5  64.5  64.5  64.5  64.5  64.5  64.5  63.   63.   63.5  63.5  63.5\n  63.5  63.5  63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.\n  63.   63.   63.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.\n  62.   62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.\n  62.   61.   58.   58.   69.   69.   69.   69.   69.   69.   69.   69.\n  69.   69.   68.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   66.5  66.5  66.5\n  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  65.   65.   65.   65.\n  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.\n  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.\n  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.\n  64.7  64.7  64.7  64.7  64.7  64.7  64.7  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.\n  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.2  64.2  64.2  64.2  64.2  64.\n  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.5  64.   64.   64.   64.\n  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   63.7  63.7  63.7\n  63.7  63.7  63.7  63.7  63.7  63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.5  63.5\n  63.5  63.5  63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   62.   62.\n  62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.7  62.7  62.7  62.7  62.7  62.7\n  62.7  62.   62.   62.   61.   61.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.\n  58.5  58.5  58.5  58.   58.   58.   58.   58.   68.5  68.5  68.5  68.5\n  68.5  68.5  68.5  68.5  68.5  68.5  67.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.\n  66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.7  66.7  66.7  66.7  66.7  66.7\n  66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5\n  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.   66.   66.\n  66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.\n  66.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   64.5  64.5  64.5  64.5\n  64.5  64.5  64.5  64.   64.   64.   64.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.\n  63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5\n  63.5  63.5  63.5  62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.\n  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.   62.   62.   62.\n  61.   61.   61.   61.   61.   61.   61.   61.   61.   61.   61.   61.\n  61.   61.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.5  70.5  70.5\n  67.   67.   67.   66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5  66.5\n  66.5  65.   65.   65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5\n  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.\n  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.\n  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.5  64.   64.   64.   64.\n  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.\n  63.   63.   63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5  63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.\n  63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.\n  63.   63.5  63.   63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5  62.5  62.   62.   62.5\n  61.   61.   61.   61.   61.   60.2  60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.\n  60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.\n  59.   59.   59.   59.   66.2  66.2  66.2  66.2  66.2  66.5  65.   65.\n  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5\n  65.5  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.\n  65.   65.   65.   64.   64.   64.   64.   63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5  63.5\n  63.5  63.5  63.5  63.   63.   63.   62.   62.   62.   62.   62.   61.\n  67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.\n  67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.   66.\n  66.   66.   66.   66.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.\n  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  65.5  63.   63.5  63.5  63.   63.   63.   63.\n  63.   63.   62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  62.5  61.5  60.   60.\n  60.   60.   60.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.\n  59.   59.   59.   59.   59.   59.   67.   67.   67.   67.   67.   66.\n  66.   66.   66.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.\n  65.5  65.5  65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   64.   64.   64.   64.\n  64.   64.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   63.   60.\n  60.   60.   60.   60.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.\n  64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   64.   63.   60.   60.   66.   66.   66.\n  63.   63.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65.   65. ] not in index'
```

`

This is the height data for the mother.  it looks like some values have a '\n', but I thought I took care of that when I converted to an xlsx file.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, you could use the `pandas` parser to read that file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Galton_height_Data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

For your plot, pass the column *names* into the [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot) method.

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='Mother', y='Height')
```